# What is the purpose or function of the TQueue.Capacity property?

Tags: delphi, generics, queue

Delphi's generic `TQueue` class has a property called `Capacity.` If the number of items in the `TQueue` exceeds its capacity, additional items are still added to the queue. [The documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Generics.Collections.TQueue.Capacity) says the property "gets or sets the queue capacity, that is, the maximum size of the queue without resizing." It sounds like a queue is kind of like a fixed length array (memory-wise)--until it's full, at which point it becomes more like a dynamic array? Is that accurate?

When would a programmer want or need to get or set a TQueue's capacity?

Comment: Just like `TList`, `TQueue` internally has a private array to maintain. As long as a reallocation can be avoided, system resources is minimized. When you add an item and the capacity has to be resized, a reallocation is needed. Usually this is done with a certain number. With the `Capacity` property, you can avoid reallocations if you beforehand know how many items the queue may contain.

Comment: Are you thinking of bounded blocking queues? When they reach their capacity, they block until another thread removes an item allowing a blocked thread to proceed. This is useful if there is a danger of the queue being overwhelmed if jobs are added faster than they can be consumed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Theory

Consider the following example, which generates a dynamic array of random integers:

```pascal
program DynArrAlloc;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows, System.SysUtils;

const
  N = 100000000;

var
  a: TArray<Integer>;
  i: Integer;
  tc1, tc2: Cardinal;

begin

  tc1 := GetTickCount;

  SetLength(a, 0);
  for i := 1 to N do
  begin
    SetLength(a, Succ(Length(a)));
    a[High(a)] := Random(1000);
  end;

  tc2 := GetTickCount;
  Writeln(tc2 - tc1);
  Readln;

end.
```

On my system, it takes 4.5 seconds to run it.

Notice that I -- in each iteration -- reallocate the array so it can hold one more item.

It would be better if I allocated a large enough array from the beginning:

```pascal
program DynArrAlloc;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows, System.SysUtils;

const
  N = 100000000;

var
  a: TArray<Integer>;
  i: Integer;
  tc1, tc2: Cardinal;

begin

  tc1 := GetTickCount;

  SetLength(a, N);
  for i := 1 to N do
    a[N - 1] := Random(1000);

  tc2 := GetTickCount;
  Writeln(tc2 - tc1);
  Readln;

end.
```

This time, the program only takes 0.6 seconds.

Hence, one should always try not to reallocate unnecessarily. Each time I reallocate in the first example, I need to ask for more memory; then I need to copy the array to the new location, and finally free the old memory. Clearly, this is very inefficient.

Unfortunately, it isn't always possible to allocate a large enough array at the start. You simply might not know the final element count.

A common strategy then is to allocate in steps: when the array is full and you need one more slot, allocate several more slots but keep track of the actual number of used slots:

```pascal
program DynArrAlloc;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows, System.SysUtils;

const
  N = 100000000;

var
  a: TArray<Integer>;
  i: Integer;
  tc1, tc2: Cardinal;
  ActualLength: Integer;

const
  AllocStep = 1024;

begin

  tc1 := GetTickCount;

  SetLength(a, AllocStep);
  ActualLength := 0;
  for i := 1 to N do
  begin
    if ActualLength = Length(a) then
      SetLength(a, Length(a) + AllocStep);
    a[ActualLength] := Random(1000);
    Inc(ActualLength);
  end;

  // Trim the excess:
  SetLength(a, ActualLength);

  tc2 := GetTickCount;
  Writeln(tc2 - tc1);
  Readln;

end.
```

Now we need 1.3 seconds.

In this example, I allocate in fixed-sized blocks. A more common strategy is probably to double the array at each reallocation (or multiply by 1.5 or something) or combine these options in a smart way.

## Applying the theory

Under the hood, `TList<T>`, `TQueue<T>`, `TStack<T>`, `TStringList` etc. need to dynamically allocate space for an unlimited number of items. To make this performant, these classes do allocate more than necessary. The `Capacity` is the number of elements you can fit in the currently allocated memory while the `Count <= Capacity` is the actual number of elements in the container.

You can set the `Capacity` property to reduce the need for intermediate allocation when you fill a container and you *do* know the final number of elements from the beginning:

```pascal
var
  L: TList<Integer>;

begin

  L := TList<Integer>.Create;
  try
    while not Something.EOF do
      L.Add(Something.GetNextValue);
  finally
    L.Free;
  end;
```

is OK and requires probably only a few reallocations, but

```pascal
  L := TList<Integer>.Create;
  try
    L.Capacity := Something.Count;
    while not Something.EOF do
      L.Add(Something.GetNextValue);
  finally
    L.Free;
  end;
```

will be faster since there will be *no* intermediate reallocations.

Comment: A common strategy of doubling the size of array only hold when the array is under specific size. Because if you would be doubling the size of you array each time you would eventually lose performance or even ran into problems because arrays would become so large despite the tact that you would be enlarging such arrays just to ad one or few more items. So in practice it is doubled in size until it reaches certain size. Then it is enlarged with fixed sized increments. What is this size at which point the array gets increased by fixed increment usually depends on size of items in an array.

Comment: @SilverWarior: That's what I meant by "[to] combine these options in a smart way"!

Answer (score 0):

Internally `TQueue` contains dynamic array that stores elements.

When item count reaches current capacity, array is reallocated (for example, doubles it's size) and you can add more and more elements.

If you know reliable limit for maximum item count, it is worth to set `Capacity`, so you will avoid memory reallocations, saving some time.